General brownian bridge from Brownian bridge
We can obtain the Brownian bridge $B_t$ on the interval $[0, T]$ using the following formula: $$B_t=X_t-\frac{t}{T}X_T,$$ where $X_t$ is a Brownian motion on $[0,T]$.
This means that $B_0=0$ and $B_T=0$.
How can I obtain a general bridge from this, i.e. $B_{t_1}=x_1$ and $B_{t_2}=x_2$?
Thank you.

First, we try to contruct $B_t$ such that: $B_0 = x_1$ and $B_T = x_2$, it suffices to add the terms $x_1 + \frac{t}{T}(x_2 -x_1)$, then we obtain:
$$B_t = X_t -\frac{t}{T}\cdot X_T +x_1 + \frac{t}{T}(x_2 -x_1)$$
Then, we change $t \mapsto f(t) = a\cdot t +b$ such that: $f(t_1)=0$ and $f(t_2 ) = T$. It suffices to solve the linear equation
$$\cases{at_1 +b = 0\\at_2 + b = T} \implies \cases{a = \frac{T}{t_2  -t_1} \\b = -\frac{t_1}{t_2-t_1}\cdot T}$$
Finally,
$$B_{f(t)} = X_{f(t)} -\frac{f(t)}{T}\cdot X_T +x_1 + \frac{f(t)}{T}(x_2 -x_1)$$
$$\implies B_t =  X_{\frac{t-t_1}{t_2-t_1}\cdot T} -\frac{t-t_1}{t_2 -t_1}\cdot X_T + x_1+\frac{t-t_1}{t_2 -t_1}(x_2-x_1) \hspace{1cm} \forall T\ge t_1$$
Then, we can choose $T = t_2$n and then
$$\color{red}{B_t =  X_{\frac{t-t_1}{t_2-t_1}\cdot t_2} -\frac{t-t_1}{t_2 -t_1}\cdot X_{t_2} + x_1+\frac{t-t_1}{t_2 -t_1}(x_2-x_1)} $$

Is there a way to prove it?

@eMathHelp I added more detail.

just one more question. In the last formula you have $T$. What is $T$? We have $t_1$, $t_2$, $x_1$, $x_2$...

@eMathHelp $T$ can take every value greater than $t_1$, for example $T = t_2$. I'll modify the answer to make it clearer.

Thank you! But not t2n, just t2.
